# Problem with table tr:hover border change

Tags: css, html-table, hover

Tested in Firefox 91.0.2 (64-bit) Windows 7.

The task: For table tr:hover, show the border-top and border-bottom in a different color so that the row is visually highlighted.

The problem: With tr:hover only the color of the border-bottom is changed.

I didn't find a solution in the already existing questions, because in these mostly no td background-color is used. Since td background-color is used in my case, the trick with a border transparency does not solve the problem. Also cellspacing does not solve the problem.

The problem seems to be that the browser first globally processes all border-top and then all border-bottom. The tr:hover border-top is overwritten by the normal border-bottom. Also an !important does not solve the problem.

The same problem exists with col border-right and border-left. However, there is no :hover active, so this problem can be solved more easily and is not a topic here. It is only included to show the problem of overwriting CSS rules.

It seems that not every CSS rule is processed individually, but they are collected and processed globally in the following order:

- border-top
- border-right
- border-bottom
- border-left

When both overlap, like in a table, the following overwrites the preceding, even with :hover! This is the problem.

So if you have a :hover border-top and also a normal border-bottom, then the :hover border-top will be overwritten by the normal border-bottom. crazy.

https://jsfiddle.net/8fh3nao6/5/

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: default;
}
th {
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.col0 {
  background: #ddd;
}
col {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
.col2 {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
tr:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.c0 {
  background: #fff;
}
.c1 {
  background: #f8a;
}
.c2 {
  background: #b3c;
}
.c3 {
  background: #aa6;
}
.c4 {
  background: #cf9;
}
.c5 {
  background: #9dd;
}
.c6 {
  background: #0f8;
}
.c7 {
  background: #44f;
}
.c8 {
  background: #88b;
}
```

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
    <col class="col0">
    <col class="col1">
    <col class="col2">
    <col class="col3">
  </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>COL 1</th>
        <th>COL 2</th>
        <th>COL 4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="c0"></td>
        <td class="c0"></td>
        <td class="c5">8,36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="c1">95,35</td>
        <td class="c3">36,25</td>
        <td class="c6">45,38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="c2">37,25</td>
        <td class="c4">15,24</td>
        <td class="c8">41,25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="c7">97,64</td>
        <td class="c3">28,73</td>
        <td class="c0">36,94</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr:hover td` instead of `tr:hover`. Borders are applied to cells not rows.

I recommend you do this if you're applying background color as well, style the cells in the row, not the row itself.

Comment: This works only in my example, not whit the rule "style the cells" only: https://jsfiddle.net/qnsu5j7k/ Now there is a real problem with the column border-left and border-right. I am looking for an ideal solution for the col border as well. There seems to be a conflict and I don't want to solve it by tricking.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work inside my app where I needed a hover border around the `<tr>`, I needed to set up a `tr:hover` style and a `tr:hover td` style. My snippet below also changes the row color on hover.

```css
// This handles the border around the row
tr:hover {
  border-color: #0CA2BF;
}

// This handles the top border for rows other than the
// first and changes the row color.
tr:hover td {
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: #0CA2BF;
  color: #0CA2BF;
}
```